# XCode 14.3.1 doesn't launch on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode14

I receive the following error while launching my project on simulator

[image]

> iPhone 14 Pro Max supports emulating this architecture, but the
> emuluation support software is not installed Domain:
> DVTDeviceIneligibilityErrorDomain
>
> Code: 26
>
> Recovery Suggestion: Install the translation support software.
>
> User Info: {
>
> DVTDeviceIneligibilityErrorTokenDescription = "uninstalled translation
> support software";
>
> DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-07-11 07:17:17 +0000";
>
> DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
>
> }

**System Information**

macOS Version 13.4.1 (Build 22F82)

Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rosetta related:

1. install Rosetta: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`.
2. Xcode: Product - Destination - Destination Architectures - Show Both, Select iPhone 14 (Rosetta) as run destination.
3. clean build and run again

Comment: Even i am also facing same problem. but i have tried this solution it is working. Thanks

Comment: I faced the same problem with xcode 15 and ios 15 and solved it using this solution.